# Cannot read property 'setValue' of undefined | Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am having an issue with my HTML component, for some reason the my method is displaying an error: 
**Cannot read property 'setValue' of undefined** when I click the edit button, however everything seems to be ok.

This is my HTML

```
<div *ngFor="let item of currentUser.myExperiences" class="mt-3">
        <div>
          <h6>{{item.companyName}} <span *ngIf="item.currentlyWorking" class="badge badge-warning">Currently
              working</span>
              <span class="float-right">
                <a class="text-warning cursor" (click)="openEditModal(item)"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></a>
              </span>
            </h6>
          <p class="text-muted p-text-sm">{{item.functions}}</p>
          <p class="text-muted p-text-sm" *ngIf="item.references">
            <strong>References:</strong>
            {{item.references}}
          </p>
          <hr>
        </div>
      </div>

<form role="form" [formGroup]="updateForm">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="functions">Funtions</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="functions" name="functions" formControlName="functions" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </form>
```

This is my TS component:

```
public openEditModal(myExperience: IMyExperience): void {
console.log(myExperience);
// Set values to controls
console.log(myExperience.id);
this.experienceId.setValue(myExperience.id);
this.companyName.setValue(myExperience.companyName);
this.functions.setValue(myExperience.functions);
this.workedYears.setValue(myExperience.workedYears);
this.references.setValue(myExperience.references);
this.currentlyWorking.setValue(myExperience.currentlyWorking);

this.updateForm.setValue({
  experienceId: this.experienceId.value,
  companyName: this.companyName.value,
  functions: this.functions.value,
  workedYears: this.workedYears.value,
  references: this.references.value,
  currentlyWorking: this.currentlyWorking.value
});

// Open the modal
this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(
  this.editModal,
  Object.assign({}, { class: 'gray modal-lg' })
);}
```

I tried displaying in console the object, but it works perfectly, however I am not sure why this is happening.

I use resolvers to pass information from the route to the component properly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is an incomplete code, what is this.experienceId ?

Comment: In the HTML file the 'item' contains the object which is the same object in the TS file. The problem is that when it's debugged it displays the error in the HTML

Comment: I cannot see it in the question added by you, can you please create a stackblitz of your issue ?

Comment: Can you share the complete TS file as I'm unsure of the types and definitions of some of the objects in your snippet (like experienceId, companyName, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **this.updateForm.patchValue** instead of **this.updateForm.setValue**.

Comment: It seems it didn't work, it displays a similar error: Cannot read property 'patchValue' of undefined. The weird thing is that console.log(myExperience); displays perfectly the object.

Comment: If you provide complete code that will be more helpful.